# Is there a syntax error in this function declaration?

Tags: c

This is from a textbook:

```
/* This function locates the address of where a new structure
   should be inserted within an existing list.
   It receives the address of a name and returns the address of a
   structure of type NameRec
*/
struct NameRec *linear Locate(char *name)
{
...
}
```

I understand it returns a pointer to a struct NameRec. Why is "linear" there and why is there a space between "linear" and "Locate"?

Comment: Looks like it might be some sort of nonstandard keyword, assuming it's C at all.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free-compiler-as-a-service. Take clang/gcc/whatever-you-prefer and compile it.

Comment: https://users.ipfw.edu/chansavj/ACY2017/ANSI_C/ANSI_C_4thEd/Solutions%20to%20Exercises%20(Windows)/Solutions/83556-0s/Ch13/pgm13-5ex3.c The URL suggests *ANSI C 4th Edition* has this method *without* the linear keyword... (CTRL+F for *This function locates the address of where a new structure*)

Comment: It is a textbook on which topic? A specific environment (compiler, preprocessor, IDE, ...)? Is it a specific C dialect for a dedicated purpose? Did it introduce some "helper headers" which are always included (automatically or by habit)? Did it explain anything about the "linear" identifier/keyword? Which book is it? Can you name the ISBN?

Comment: It's a huge block of code and 4 pages in my textbook. I'd rather not type up the entire thing if there's a simple answer. It's from A First Book of ANSI C: https://www.amazon.com/First-Book-Fourth-Introduction-Programming/dp/1418835560. It's Program 13.7 on page 636.

Comment: The simple answer is to look for the definition of `linear` in those 4 pages.

Comment: There is no definition of linear, there is no mention of the word anywhere in the code block, nor the text preceding or proceeding the program.

Comment: How about in the index?

Comment: Just "linear search, 416-419".

Comment: Well, then I'd say it's a typo, and I would delete it (assuming you intend to try to run the program).

Comment: OK, I'm going to assume it's a typo. It's actually referenced like that multiple times (in its function prototype and when it is called). I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo in the book. See the locate function here:

https://users.ipfw.edu/chansavj/ACY2017/ANSI_C/ANSI_C_4thEd/Solutions%20to%20Exercises%20(Windows)/Solutions/83556-0s/Ch13/pgm13-5ex3.c

(Posted by ta.speot.is in the comments)

Answer (score 3):

```
#define linear
```

will *make* it syntactically correct even if it wasn't before (though, technically, you'd probably want a `#undef linear` beforehand to avoid possible conflicting macro definitions).

It depends entirely on the *context* of the code, which you haven't shown. As it stands now, with no header inclusions or definitions like `-Dlinear=` on the compiler command line, it would not compile in a standards-conformant environment without extensions.

The best way to tell, of course, is to just try to actually compile the thing and see what happens :-)

Given that the [solutions link](https://users.ipfw.edu/chansavj/ACY2017/ANSI_C/ANSI_C_4thEd/Solutions%20to%20Exercises%20(Windows)/Solutions/83556-0s/Ch13/pgm13-5ex3.c) for chapter 13 (the one you're asking about) has *no* mention of the `linear` word in the solution, I'd say it's a safe bet to assume your book is incorrect. I'd consider contacting the author (apparently currently working at FDU in New Jersey) to clear it up.

Comment: Yes, `linear` could be some way to annotate that this method has linear O(1) complexity or similar.